# How do I find the type of the file through the link of the google drive?

Tags: python, if-statement, google-drive-api

I have many files in my google drive. I want to read it according to it's type like .txt,.pdf,.doc etc. I am able to read it separately, but I want that through the use of if else or any other condition.

Here is the code for read .txt file

```
file_path=link of google drive    
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen(file_path)
html = response.read()
text=html.decode('utf8')
print(text)
```

Here is the code for read .pdf file.

```
import requests, PyPDF2


url = file_path
response = requests.get(url)
my_raw_data = response.content

with open("my_pdf.pdf", 'wb') as my_data:
    my_data.write(my_raw_data)

open_pdf_file = open("my_pdf.pdf", 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open_pdf_file)
if read_pdf.isEncrypted:
    read_pdf.decrypt("")
    print(read_pdf.getPage(0).extractText())

else:
    print(read_pdf.getPage(0).extractText())
```

here is code for google drive API

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload


# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

def main():
  creds = None
  # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
  # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
  # time.
  if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
      with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
          creds = pickle.load(token)
  # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
  if not creds or not creds.valid:
      if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
          creds.refresh(Request())
      else:
          flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
              'credentials.json', SCOPES)
          creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
      # Save the credentials for the next run
      with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
          pickle.dump(creds, token)

  service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)


  # Call the Drive v3 API
  results = service.files().list(
      pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
  items = results.get('files', [])

  if not items:
      print('No files found.')
  else:
      print('Files:')
      for item in items:
          print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

  if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

    file_metadata = {'name': 'unnamed.jpg'}
    media = MediaFileUpload('unnamed.jpg',
                        mimetype='image/jpeg')
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
    print ('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
  print(file)
```

Now I want to give a conditions that if the file type is .txt then then it will read accordingly, if file type is .pdf then it will read pdf like that.

So, how can I find the type of the file and read all type of file in one code through the conditions?

Comment: I think that in this case, it is required to use "Files: list" method of Drive API. But, from your question, I cannot see your current script for using Drive API. So, can you provide your current script for retrieving the file metadata using Drive API?

Comment: Have you tried using [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)? The quickstart shows how to list the files from your drive https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python

Comment: added the code for drive api.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: But I am not able to find the file list as shown .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not 100% sure i understand what you want to do.

If you want just get back files of a specific mime type then you can use the  q parameter for the [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) method to search for files by mimeType

```
mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.document'
```

Something like this

```
    response = service.files().list(q=f"mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'",
                                    fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
).execute()
```

You could also do it with a single file.list request and then detect the mime type of each file. that is returned.

```
 "files": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "1x8-vD-XiXEEA5Spf3qp8x2wltablGF22Lpwup8VtxNY",
   "name": "Experts Activity Dump go/ExpertsActivities",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  },
```

Depending upon the mime type of the file returned you can use a different open method.  Just remember there are some file types you will not be able to open in this manner.  Any drive types like sheets and docs, you will need to export first and then open them in a format you can handle.

Comment: Updated the code for Drive API. But I am not able to find the file list as shown by you.